# magento grand total update by ajax call

Tags: magento

during checkout when we have to move into payment method here is wallet option what i have done
[image]

after click on checkbox if customer want to use wallet amount
it will show the calculation like this
[image]

so i want to update my grand total amount as per calculation 
so i want to update

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteData= $quote->getData();
$grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the observer on

```
checkout_onepage_savepayment_save_after
```

and then you can send rendered block of review order.
from controller in response and then update order review block by jquery/javascript/prototype.

This is the sample code of rendering payment method which i used once for rendering payment method block through ajax call.

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
                                $update = $layout->getUpdate();
                                $update->load('checkout_onepage_paymentmethod');
                                $layout->generateXml();
                                $layout->generateBlocks();
                                $output = $layout->getOutput();
```

Comment: did u check above attached images?
please check image u can easily understand the flow.

Comment: just click on "enter image description here". u can able to see the images

Comment: @suhel i checked your question, all i can give u an idea. i can not create same functionality in my system and give you the exact running code.

Comment: but i am asking about how to update the new grand price not asking about how rendere block. 
so kindly help if you know to change or update new price if we want add some custome fee or remove some amount

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$quote->setGrandTotal(1000)
                            ->setBaseGrandTotal(700)
                            ->setSubtotalWithDiscount(700)
                            ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(1000)
                            ->save();
```

you can set the price of quote then you have to render that review block to see the price changes. I have this will help you